# Excel VBA - append formatted text to cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to add a "padding-bottom" to a cell in VBA.

A way to get what I need might be to append to a cell a char  with smaller font size (let's say a small dot) in a new line.

How can I achieve this in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will insert "my text" into range A1, you can adapt it as you need.

It works as follows:

1. Get the current number of characters in Range A1 (lOldTextLen)
2. Insert two line breaks and "my text" into Range A1
3. Update the characters in Range A1 to font size 8, starting from the end of the previous text (using lOldTextLen)

   ```
   Dim sText As String 
   Dim lOldTextLen As Long

   sText = "my text"
   lOldTextLen = Len(Range("a1"))

   Range("a1").Value = Range("a1").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & sText

   Range("a1").Characters(lOldTextLen + 1).Font.Size = 8
   ```

Comment: Just to be clear, this will remove any pre-existing richt text formatting from the cell, only applying the new rich text format to the new line